# Can't set UILabel width proportional with UITableViewCell width in storyboard by Autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard, label

I have a simple tableview cell with one label (named Bio).
Tableview in storyboard. I want that this label should be change in width according to cell width. e.g. 40% of cell width.

It's easy to do in any view. But can't find the option when I control-drag label to cell content view. The "Equal Widths" is missing. (Also "Equal Heights" missing). Is anything I am missing or its XCode(6.1.1) bug ??

[image: Dragging]

[image: AutoLayout option]

Comment: Please set the relation with ContentView

Comment: I did like this way. But nothing change. May be its issue of XCode 6.1.1.

Comment: Why are you still using XCode 6? 6.1.1 is almost 2 years old.